Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence
The following code throws me an error:
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Lambda, LSTM, TimeDistributed
from tensorflow.keras import Input

feat1 = [np.random.random((5, 7))]*200
feat2 = [np.random.random((5, 7))]*200
label = [np.random.random((5))]*200

def gen_Xny():
    for ft1, ft2, lbl  in zip(feat1, feat1, label):
        yield list(zip(ft1, ft2)), list(zip(lbl))
    
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    gen_Xny,
    output_signature=(
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(5, 2, 7)),
        tf.TensorSpec(shape=(5, 1))
    )
)

df = dataset.batch(1)

input = Input((5, 2, 7))
channel = Lambda(lambda x: x[:, :, 0])(input)
channel = LSTM(50, return_sequences=True)(channel)
timedist = TimeDistributed(Dense(1))(channel)
model = Model(inputs=input, outputs=timedist)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(df, epochs=10)

The specific error is:

I tensorflow/core/framework/local_rendezvous.cc:404] Local rendezvous is aborting with status: OUT_OF_RANGE: End of sequence.
[[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]

It then starts another epoch, which I don't understand at all. On the first epoch, it gives me the warning:

UserWarning: Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least steps_per_epoch * epochs batches. You may need to use the .repeat() function when building your dataset.

What's strange is that this only seems to happen on epochs that are powers of two, and on all epochs that are powers of two. What's even stranger is that if i set the steps_per_epoch to be way larger than the number of batches in the dataset, it still manages to iterate through batches that don't exist. I have seen others posting similar issues before, and there's a thread on github describing a similar issue (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36126), but that was apparently fixed four years ago and nothing I have found has worked and I have been looking for about two days. I don't know how it is iterating through the batches, but it seems to me like it's reading them the wrong way. I may just have structured the data wrong.
Setting the steps_per_epoch and using .repeat() did nothing. I also tried restructuring the data, which likewise accomplished squat.
This is a simplified version of the code, just to illustrate the problem.

Summary
Not sure it helps, but I was running into this problem on Tensorflow version: 2.17.0 with Python version 3.10.4.
I was using a DirectoryIterator and I needed to comment out the steps per epochs (and steps for validation) for the error to go away:
# Comment out steps per epoch and fixed it
model.fit(x=train_batches,
          # steps_per_epoch=len(train_batches),
          validation_data=valid_batches,
          # validation_steps=len(valid_batches),
          epochs=10,
          verbose=2
          )

Details
From Deep Lizard's Blog post on it (I was walking through their tutorials):

Recently, there was a change introduced by TensorFlow that now
requires us to pass in another parameter to the fit() function when
our data is stored in an infinitely repeating data set, like a
DirectoryIterator.
Note that a DirectoryIterator is indeed an infinitely repeating data
set, as the batches of data generated by the iterator will continue to
come infinitely as long as we want them to. You can see this by
passing the iterator to the built-in Python next() function and
running it over and over again to infinitely generate new batches of
data.

So, I added the steps per epoch (since I thought it was telling me to do that) and it cut off the data early I guess. I didn't really understand that until I read this comment on the bug.
The default behavior was different prior to that, so maybe bumping up your version will help (since it doesn't look like you specify the parameters I removed).
